# How do I get Windows drive letters off of an AWS EC2 instance's attached volumes so I can use them in terraform for CloudWatch alarms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I have an automatic alerting system built in AWS via terraform that scans the VPC for all Windows EC2 instances and their attached volumes. I need to create an alarm that measures low disk space on the volumes so that I get alerted when the disks drop below, say, 10% free space. It appears that I need the drive letter assigned to the mounted EBS volume as one of the dimensions. Using 'terraform show', I see that the information under 'ebs_block_device' and 'root_block_device' do indeed give the '/dev/sda1' and 'xvdb' linux-style device assignments, and there is a mapping given by Amazon to map target devices to their logical names here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html

but the disks we have mounted don't always follow a sequential path of Disk0 = C:, Disk1=D:, ... etc. Below is the code I have so far:

```
data "aws_instances" "all_ec2" {
  instance_state_names = ["running", "stopped", "pending", "stopping"]

  instance_tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_tag
  }
}

data "aws_instance" "each_ec2" {
  for_each    = toset(data.aws_instances.all_ec2.ids)
  instance_id = each.key
}
    
    
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ebs_disk_capacity" {
  for_each                  = toset(data.aws_instances.all_ec2.ids)
  alarm_name                = "EBS Disk capacity - ${data.aws_instance.each_ec2[each.key].tags["Name"]}"
  alarm_description         = "The volume is nearly full (default: disk space is <= 10%)."
  comparison_operator       = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = 1
  threshold                 = 10
  period                    = 60
  namespace                 = "CWAgent"
  metric_name               = "LogicalDisk % Free Space"
  statistic                 = "Maximum"
  alarm_actions             = [aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts_topic.arn]
  insufficient_data_actions = [aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts_topic.arn]
  ok_actions                = [aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts_topic.arn]
  dimensions = {
    InstanceId   = each.value,
    objectname   = "LogicalDisk",
    instance     = "C:" # <-- HARDCODED, THIS NEEDS TO BE AUTOMATIC 
    ImageId      = data.aws_instance.each_ec2[each.key].ami,
    InstanceType = data.aws_instance.each_ec2[each.key].instance_type
  }
}
```

My feeling is that I'll need to write a powershell script to get the disk mappings, but then how to bubble that up to the AWS level to leverage for what I need in this case?

Comment: As a part of `aws_instance` data source, this also gets exported: `ebs_block_device`. There is a `device_name` and `virtual_name` as a part of the `ebs_block_device`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance#ebs_block_device. So you might try with `instance = data.aws_instance.each_ec2[each.key].ebs_block_device.virtual_name` or `instance = data.aws_instance.each_ec2[each.key].ebs_block_device.device_name` I guess.

Comment: @MarkoE - Yes, I did see ebs_block_device.device_name, but that has the AWS devnode assignment (e.g. /dev/sda1, xvdb, etc.) A 'terraform show' confirms this. I don't see a 'virtual_name' attribute in my terraform show.

Comment: virtual_name appears for ephemeral volumes, but I'm using EBS backed instance storage.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, scrolled a bit up.